# Jena dataset update

Tags: sparql, jena

I have a SPARQL update on a named graph in a jena dataset. The problem is that the dataset is not updated, i.e. the triples are not inserted. The same query runs when using Jena Fuseki as a triple store instead of the in-memory jena dataset.

My code:

```java
Dataset dataset = RDFDataMgr.loadDataset("my_dataset.nq", RDFLanguages.NQUADS);

String updateQuery = "PREFIX  mygraph:  <http://example.org#mygraph> " +
"WITH mygraph: " + 
"INSERT {   ... some triples ... } WHERE { ... some triples ... } ";

UpdateRequest update = UpdateFactory.create(updateQuery);
UpdateProcessor processor = UpdateExecutionFactory.create(update, dataset);
processor.execute();
```

I don't see why the update does not work and the number of triples remains the same before and after the update. I want to update a named graph within the dataset and the graph is indicated in the query. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: 1) how do you see that the triples haven't been inserted? 2) did you check the named graph afterwards via a `SELECT` query or just the Java API methods? 3) Are you sure that your `WHERE` part matches any data?

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: I checked the changes by counting the graphs and triples before and after the update operation with a ```SELECT``` query. I use version 3.3.

Comment: That's what I thought. We don't know your `SELECT` query yet, but a simple `SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?cnt) WHERE {?s ?p ?o}`  will not work because you added data to a named graph and the `SELECT` query will only query the default graph. You have to run `SELECT (COUNT(*) AS ?cnt) WHERE {{?s ?p ?o} UNION {GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o}}}` to count all triples in your dataset

Comment: By the way, we're currently at version `4.2.0`, you're using a version from May 2017 - any reason for this?

Comment: Yes, that is the way I count the triples. Maybe it is the case that it doesn't insert the data if the graph is not existing the first time?

Comment: I found the solution: the update query works fine, iff the graph exists in the dataset. Otherwise it is necessary to first create a model, populate it and add it to the dataset.

UninformedUser, AndyS: Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Ok, according to the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#insertData): *"If an operation tries to insert into a graph that does not exist, then that graph SHOULD be created; again, there may be implementations providing an update service over a fixed set of graphs which in such case MUST return with failure for update requests that would create an unallowed graph. If no data is to be inserted, then no graph will be created."* - so from my understanding the graph should be created, you should try with latest Jena `4.2.0`

Comment: if that doesn't work, just use `CREATE GRAPH mygraph:; WITH mygraph: ... `